# How to define multiple controllers for one view in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-routing

What I tried :

```
 $routeProvider
     .when('/paintings',
         {
             controller: 'imageController' , 'getPaintingImages'
             templateUrl: 'paintings.html'
         })
     .when('/foods',
         {
             controller: 'imageController' , 'getFoodImages'
             templateUrl: 'food.html'
         })
```

I wanted getPaintingImages and getFoodImages to get the list of paintings/foods from a factory, and imageController to manipulate the images. But only first controller gets called.

Earlier I wrote code to get the images in imageController only,

```
myWebsite.controller('imageController', function imageController($scope, getPaintings){

    $scope.images = getPaintings.images();                // but need to make this work for different set of images
    $scope.imageCount = countObjectElements($scope.images);     
    $scope.selectedImage = $scope.images[0];
    $scope.selectedImageIndex = 0;

    $scope.updateSelectedImage = function(img) {        
        $scope.selectedImage = img;
        $scope.selectedImageIndex = $scope.images.indexOf(img);     
    };  
    $scope.updateSelectedImageIndex = function(val) {       

        alert($scope.imageOf);
        if($scope.selectedImageIndex <= 0)
            $scope.selectedImageIndex = $scope.imageCount;

        $scope.selectedImageIndex = ($scope.selectedImageIndex + val) % $scope.imageCount;      
        $scope.selectedImage = $scope.images[$scope.selectedImageIndex];
    };
});
```

As I am a beginner in angularJS, I am not sure if creating multiple controllers a solution for re-using imageController ? If yes how to do this, if not how to re-use imageController to work for different set of images. In case of functions, re-use of function is generally by parameter passing. But here I am wondering how can a controller take parameters as it gets called for a view internally ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

getPaintingImages and getFoodImages are using a factory to get the images you say. It sounds like you could use something like resolve: in the routeProvider so that the images the imageController needs are there for them when it is called.

Something like (assuming your getPaintings and getFoods are services/factory and get images are something that returns a $promise that resolve into images i.e. $http request):

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/paintings', {
        controller: 'imageController',
        templateUrl: 'paintings.html',
        resolve: { 
            images: function($q, getPainting) {
                getPainting.images();
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/foods', {
        controller: 'imageController',
        templateUrl: 'food.html',
        resolve: { 
            images: function($q, getFoods) {
                getFoods.images();
            }
        }
    })
```

Then you could just access images like:

```
myWebsite.controller('imageController', ['$scope', 'images', function ($scope, images){
    ...
}]);
```

Answer (score 6):

How about making imageController the parent:

```
<body ng-controller="imageController">  
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set a controller on a view the controller requests an isolated scope for the view, you cannot have 2 isolated scopes on the same view, that would cause an error. The only options you have is to apply the controller to the parent, or call the `imageController` function inside the first controller and pass the `$scope`